# How to use images in List-of-Values of "Select List" Items?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to use images in the LOV (list of values) of "Select List" Items in Apex 5

[image]

Following this thread
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3969943

I can change the background color of elements of the list, adding this code to Element>Properties>Advanced>Post Text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("ElementId")[3].style.backgroundColor= 'cyan';
</script>
```

but when trying to set an image, nothing happens

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("ElementId")[3].style.backgroundImage= "imageUrl";
</script>
```

What is the right way to set the image?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine but images aren't support by IE so if this is the browser you are using this is what the problem will be. It will work in Firefox.